# Deploying visual studio 2012 c# windows application

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, deployment

i created a windows application that uses system.xml and system.io libraries, it reads and writes into a specific file (in same directory).
after i am done, i run the .exe file and its perfectly fine BUT when i tried it on any other computer, it gives an error and doesn't work(doesn't even open).
i think that i should attach some library files such as the xml library ?
I tried publishing as installation file and it also doesn't work
i don't know and don't know how to do that, please help.

Comment: You need to copy, to the other computer, all the dependencies required for the program to work. (All .dll files)

Answer (score 0):

`System.XML` and `System.IO` are part of the .NET Framework. Check which .NET Framework version your solution is compiled for (in the project settings in Visual Studio). Default for Visual Studio 2015 is the .NET Framework 4.5.2, which is not installed by default on Windows 7! You need to install it for your application to work, but you don't need to copy any DLLs manually.

You can find the official download here

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42642

[image]